# How to insert text and image in a TouchableOpacity?

Tags: css, react-native

I have a login button and I would like to place a Login text at the center of the button and an image (scaling it properly) on the right edge of the button, far away from the text.

Currently I am using an Icon from the Vector Icons library in the following way:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonLoginTouchable} onPress={this.loginUser.bind(this)}>
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <Text style={{ color: '#ffffff', fontWeight: '700', paddingLeft: '46%' }}>Login</Text>
        <Icon name="arrow-right" color='#fff' size={15} style={{ paddingLeft: '33%' }} />
    </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Which is probably also not the best way to do it. Now I would like to replace the Icon with an Image, so I wrote instead the following code:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonLoginTouchable} onPress={this.loginUser.bind(this)}>
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <Text style={{ color: '#ffffff', fontWeight: '700', flex: 0.9 }}>Login</Text>
        <Image source={require('../../common/arrow.png')} resizeMode='contain' style={{ height: 10 }} />
    </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

This way the image scale and it is placed somehow on the right but it is not anymore horizontally aligned (and I can't understand why).

Does anyone know the best way to achieve the style I am looking for?

Comment: Add `flex:1` to style in `<Text style={{flex:1,....}}...` shall help **and remove the padding...**

Comment: @Ponleu I modified the code with flex (look at my edit) and it certainly looks better but my arrow is still not vertically aligned.

Comment: Modify View to ` <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent : 'center'}}>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use it like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={{flexDirection:"row",alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center'}}>
    <Text style={{flex:.8}}>Login</Text>
    <Image source={require('../../common/arrow.png')} resizeMode='contain' style={{flex:.2 }} />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

See the below simple example to add image in touchableopacity component in react native. It is very simple you need to wrap image component inside the touchableopacity component.

```
<TouchableOpacity activeOpacity = { .5 } onPress={ this.callFun }> 
 <Image source={require('./images/sample_image_button.png')} style = {styles.ImagesStyle} />          
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Please, read the description of the question, not just the question itself.